# How to transform basis functions to satisfy a restriction

Tags: interaction, basis-function, restrictions

I am trying to find a way to methodically transform a set of basis functions to satisfy a restriction so that the coefficient of the first basis function at a specific value of $x$ can have a special interpretation.  The ultimate goal is so that I can put a Bayesian prior on the effect of treatment at a given value of $x$ when $x$ interacts with treatment.

For example, consider an ordinary regression model with a cubic polynomial in a covariate $x$ and a treatment variable $T$ (a binary grouping) taking on values $A$ and $B$.  Treatment is allowed to interact with $x$ in a general (nonlinear) way.  $[u]$ is Knuth's notation, i.e., an indicator variable that is 1 when $u$ is true, 0 otherwise.

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
E(Y | T, x) = & \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}[T=B] + \beta_{2}x + \beta_{3}x^{2} + \beta_{4}x^{3} + \beta_{5}x[T=B] \\
 &+ \beta_{6}x^{2}[T=B] + \beta_{7}x^{3}[T=B]
\end{array}
$$

The B:A treatment effect is the $x$-specific $B - A$ difference in means $E(Y | T=B, x) - E(Y | T=A, x)$ which is

$$
\beta_{1} + \beta_{5}x + \beta_{6}x^{2} + \beta_{7}x^{3}
$$

If I wanted to put a prior on the treatment effect of $x$ on $y$ at $x=10$ I would just subtract 10 from $x$ before fitting the model and I would have it as $\beta_{1}$, so I could set my informative prior on $\beta_{1}$.

The question is how to arrive at transformed basis functions more generally.  The particular need I have is to use a linear spline to allow for sharp changes at three $x$ values.  If there are 3 knots (points at which the slope of $x$ changes) at $x=t_{i}, i=1,2,3$, convenient basis functions are

$$
x, (x-t_{1})_{+}, (x-t_{2})_{+}, (x-t_{3})_{+}
$$

where $(w)_{+}$ denotes $w$ if it is positive and zero otherwise.  These basis functions enforce zero-order continuity, i.e., the fitted piecewise linear function will not have vertical jumps.

I have been unable to to translate these basis functions so that the treatment effect is isolated to $\beta_{1}$ as in the regular polynomial case.  Is there a general manipulation that can be used here, or another linear spline basis function that will do the trick?

Because of software considerations I don't want to create special terms in the model that combine main effects and interactions but would like to find a solution if possible that allows a special basis function in $x$ to interact with $T$ in the usual multiplicative way.

**Update**: A more general solution for my Bayesian purpose is to specify priors for linear combinations of $\beta$s.  This is not hard to do: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/putting-priors-on-transformed-parameters/2488/8 .  But I would still would appreciate learning about basis function tricks.

**Update 2**: I've fully implemented the Stan approach for the priors [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg.html#sec-genreg-pcontrast)

Comment: Define treatment effect, please. For example, is treatment $\geq 0$? How does this question relate to a density function, or does it? I do not understand what the question is in terms of what is being modelled. Would you elaborate a bit on that, please?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify.  This is not really related to density functions.

Comment: Is the question pharmacodynamical? I cannot visualize the meaning or physics of the parameters without more information, so the constraints, orthogonality or lack of it for the parameters, and meaning of the question escapes me.

Comment: That does not matter at all for the question at hand.  I'm considering the estimation of the B-A difference in means in a parallel-group study with univariate Y, and this also pertains to logistic regression and most other models instead of just OLS, if you replace $E(Y|X)$ with e.g. $\Pr(Y=1|X)$.